# Is it possible to draw grid lines using AVFoundation Framework in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, image, gridview, avfoundation, ios-camera

I am creating the app like VSCO Cam, so I imported AVFoundation framework to my project and used AVCaptureSession to create the custom camera.I also need to create the custom filters as same as VSCO Cam.
    Now I want to add the gridlines on the camera by clicking a button.I searched for more tutorials, but I couldn't sort it out.I tried drawing grid lines using AVCaptureManager by seeing this link [how to draw grid lines when camera is open avcapturemanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226496/how-to-draw-grid-lines-when-camera-is-open-avcapturemanager/18226786#18226786), But I cannot overlay the view with camera view.I'm a new bee to development.
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.Create a tranparent UIView and place it on top of the camera preview. Then you can draw what ever you like in that view or you can append the image.