# How to create grid view in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Example: iPhone camera grid

[image: Example: iPhone camera grid]

I'm trying to display a grid (3 X 3) like the one which appears when you turn on from Settings > Camera > Grid. I already read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226496/how-to-draw-grid-lines-when-camera-is-open-avcapturemanager/18226786), and I tried adding png as well, but I can't replicate like the image I attached.

Thanks for reading this post!

Comment: Do u want only gird work or camera thing also?

Comment: For now, my main goal is to make a similar grid view and then, later on, make it work with a camera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body : some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Divider()
                Spacer()
                Divider()
                Spacer()
            }

            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Divider()
                Spacer()
                Divider()
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, this is very simple but very smart!